# Issue in changing textbox background color by using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to pass the texttbox id to javascript function and change the color of the textbox if the value is null.

```
function fnOnUpdateValidatorsNewChangeChange(txtid) {
    var txt1 = document.getElementById(txtid);
    var Value = document.getElementById(txtid).value
    if (Value == "") {
        txt1.style.background = "#FFF000";
    }
}


<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtlabelID" class="textbox" TextMode="SingleLine" 
onchange="fnOnUpdateValidatorsNewChangeChange('<%= txtlabelID.ClientID %>')"
```

But it's getting Null error.

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine just terminate the statement by semi colon.
`var Value = document.getElementById(txtid).value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you not need to pass ID of textbox and find textbox using the same id ..

You just pass `this`  as a textbox in argument for E.g.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtlabelID" class="textbox" TextMode="SingleLine" 
onchange="fnOnUpdateValidatorsNewChangeChange(this)"





 function fnOnUpdateValidatorsNewChangeChange(txtbox) {
    if (txtbox.value == "") {
        txtbox.style.background = "#FFF000";
    }
    else
        txtbox.style.background = "";
}
```

Is it more Simple ??